# railsで画像を表示したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsで画像投稿機能を作っているのですが、画像が表示できずエラーが出ている状態です。
一応編集をしてみたいのですが、一緒のエラーが出ている状態です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<img src="<%= "/#{post.user.image_name}" %>">
    </div>
    <div class="post-right">
      <div class="post-user-name">
        <!-- link_toメソッドを用いて、ユーザー詳細ページへのリンクを作成してください -->

      </div>
        <%= link_to(post.content, "/posts/#{post.id}") %>

        <% if @post.photo? %>  <!-- アップロード画像がある場合に実行する -->
          <p>
            <strong>photo:</strong>
            <%= image_tag @post.photo.url %><!-- userインスタンスの画像ファイルのURLを取得し表示 -->
          </p>
        <% end %>

    </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

エラーが出ている行の`@post`が`nil`であることがエラー画面からわかります。上の行では`post`が使われておりそちらは動作していることから、`post`が正しいのではないかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の通りエラーのほうは消えました。